# Разделить число на слагаемые используя массив

Tags: c++, c

Доброго времени суток уважаемое комьюнити Stack Overflow.

Мне необходимо создать алгоритм, котороый бы разделил число на слагаемые по принципу: Сначала идут найбольшие элементы массива.
Слагаемые берутся из массива: `capacity[13] = { 100,50,20,10,5,2,1,0.50,0.20,0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01 }`
Приведу простой пример:

> 0.6 = 0.5 + 0.1

или

> 0.75 = 0.5 + 0.2 + 0.05

В конце функция возвращает значение **1**. 
В консоль выписывает *только слагаемые*.

Сообственно сама функция:

```
 double payback(double re)
{
    double capacity[13] = { 100,50,20,10,5,2,1,0.50,0.20,0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01 };
    double re1 = re;
    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            double re2 = 0;
            re2 = re1 - capacity[i];
            if (re2 > 0)
            {
                re1 = re1 - capacity[i];
                printf("%g ", capacity[i]);

                break;
            }
            else if (re2 == 0)
            {
                printf("%g ", capacity[i]);
                goto end;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
end:;       
    return 1;
}
```

Спасибо, за уделенное время!

PS. Извините за плохое оформление :)

Comment: Сразу - не используйте `double` - получите неприятности при сравнениях. Работайте с копейками :) - т.е. с целыми числами и в 100 раз большими. А дальше - простой жадный алгоритм...

Comment: @Harry Вы имеете ввиду сконвертировать 'double' в 'int'?

Comment: Задача непонятная однако :) почему `0.75 = 0.5 + 0.2 + 0.05` а не `0.75 = 0.7 + 0.05` или `0.75 = 0.5 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.05` ? и тд.

Comment: @NewView Необходимо что-бы все слогаемые были числами, которые есть в массиве `capacity[13]`

Comment: сл**А**гаемые - от слова "слАживать"

Comment: @igor Спасибо! Исправил.

Comment: Не просто конвертировать, а использовать массив 10000,5000,2000,1000,500,200,100,50,20,10, 5, 2, 1 - и работать с целыми числами.

Comment: @Harry Благодарю за столь простое решение!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комментарию пользователя Harry, я смог довести свой проект до рабочего состояния!

Решение заключается в том, что-бы использовать при сравнении **целочисленные типы данных**.

```
double payback(double re)
{
    double capacity[13] = { 100,50,20,10,5,2,1,0.50,0.20,0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01 };
    int check[13] = { 10000,5000,2000,1000,500,200,100,50,20,10, 5, 2, 1 };
    int re1 = re * 100;
    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            int re2 = 0;
            re2 = re1 - check[i];
            if (re2 > 0)
            {
                re1 = re1 - check[i];
                printf("%g ", capacity[i]);

                break;
            }
            else if (re2 == 0)
            {
                printf("%g ", capacity[i]);
                goto end;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
end:;       
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, код неверный. Что он даст для re=4 или 900? Подсказка -  `while`